# An inequality concerning arithmetic mean

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Suppose we have two vectors $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)^T, y = (y_1, \dots, y_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where the suberscript denote the components. Let $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j} {n} \mathbf 1$ where $\mathbf 1$ is the all $1$ vector. I want to find some upper bound for $\|x-y\|_2^2$ in terms of $\|\bar{x} - \bar{y}\|_2^2$. 
\begin{align*}
\|x-y\|_2^2 = (x_1 - y_1)^2 + \dots + (x_n - y_n)^2 \\
\|\bar{x} - \bar{y} \|_2^2 = (1/n) \left( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j - \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \right)^2.
\end{align*}

As pointed by the comment, we need to put the assumption $\bar{x} \neq \bar{y}$. But I am not sure whether there exists some sensible constant $C$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|x-y\|_2^2 \le C \| \bar{x} - \bar{y} \|_2^2.
\end{align*}
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot have a constant C such that $||x-y||_2 \leq || \bar {x} - \bar {y}||_2$ because the right side can be 0 without x and y being equal. What kind of inequality are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What if we put the assumption that $\bar{x} \neq \bar{y}$? Will this yield a sensible bound with constant $C$?

Comment: Does your claimed value of $C=(n+1)$ work for $x=(0,99)$, $y=(50,50)$?

Comment: You are right. I made a silly mistake. Do you think such constant C exists?

Comment: No such constant exists, even with the assumption $\bar{x} \neq \bar{y}$. Consider $x = (1, 0)$ and $y = (K, -K)$ with large $K$.

Comment: Nice example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such estimate can exist. The essential reason is what Kavi Rama Murthy said [in above comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617187/an-inequality-concerning-arithmetic-mean#comment5405171_2617187):

> ... because the right side can be $0$ without $x$ and $y$ being equal.

For continuity reasons it does not help to add the assumption $\bar{x} \neq \bar{y}$. A concrete counter-example is

$$
 x = (1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)^T \, , \, y = (K, -K, 0, \ldots, 0)^T
$$
for large $K$.

Comment: If the inequality holds when $\bar {x} \neq \bar {y}$ it will hold even when $\bar {x} = \bar {y}$, by continuity!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Yes, that what I tried to express with *"For continuity reasons ..."*